How do I assign the length of a list to a double in Flutter?
I am trying to assign the length of a list to a double and it says that an instance member can't be accessed in an initializer:
List numlist = [1,2,3,4,5];
double size = numlist.length.toDouble();

Is there a way to get this to work?

Use Getter: Dynamically computes the size whenever it is accessed, ensuring it is always up-to-date with the current length of the list.
For example:
  List<int> numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  double get size {
    return numlist.length.toDouble();
  }
  
  void test() {
    final result = size;
  }


use late to declare a variable that will be initialized at a later time
List numlist = [1,2,3,4,5];
late double size = numlist.length.toDouble();

in this case, size should be initialized after numlist

From the error message, I seems that the variables you are trying to define are instance members of a class. In that case, you could also use constructor initializers:
class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.list)
      : length = list.length.toDouble();
  final List<num> list;
  final double length;
}

The other options are:

declaring a getter like mikeyyang suggested,
marking length as a late variable and initializing it where you define it as Zhentao suggested.

